# Search and open a file in SharePoint from excel

Tags: sharepoint

I wish to open a file which is saved in our SharePoint by our engineering team at different location in the world. The exact location of the files are scattered in different area of the SharePoint. As an engineering document controller I may need to open drawings often in the SharePoint. Ex. the file name of a drawing - PS14565-V1200-MS-MC-A4-0001_0.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried from your end?

Comment: No Code is available. Linking one by one with the excel cells. Actually I want to have a user defined function in excel coded in VBA to search and open the file in SharePoint. Thank you sir.